# How to render input inside of label for checkboxes?

Tags: theming, 8, forms

I have a form field with a list of checkboxes, but the inputs are outside of the label. Theming requirements dictate that the input must be inside the label, as well as have a span with the form option name in the input tag.

I tried looking at `form-element.html.twig` and `form-element-label.html.twig` but don't see a way to combine the two.

Comment: its should be input--checkbox.html.twig

Comment: Can't you just use css and `display: inline-block;` or `float:left;` to make them inline?

Comment: The requirement is the input has to be inside of the label, that is the markup that was delivered to me and already styled for.

Comment: @Kevin tell your themer to get good, who the .... uses `label` to style everything. Tell him to use the class from the div that wraps/is before `<label>`

Comment: @Kevin you should create a twig template for your form. Maybe that will be easier for your themer to understand/work with.

Comment: It isn't just style on the label; she had to do styled checkboxes, which required placing the input inside of the label to achieve. CSS alone won't cut it. With checkboxes, it is also very difficult to get `<label><input ..><span>Title!</span></input></label>` out of the box. I eventually figured it out, will post answer later.

Comment: @Kevin I have the same problem, will you give me the answer you found for this?